# Sumarle 1 a un resultado de consulta mysql

Tags: mysql, date, sum

Buen día, parte de mi proyecto requiere saber los días transcurridos entre una fecha y otra.
actualmente almaceno información en mysql para la cual me guarda en una tabla llamada vacaciones.

| nombre | inicio | fin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jose | 2021/12/20 | 2021/12/24 |
| Juan | 2021/12/20 | 2021/12/20 |

tengo una consulta

```
select nombre DATE_FORMAT(inicio, "%d-%m-%Y"),DATE_FORMAT(fin, "%d-%m-%Y"), TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, inicio, fin) AS dias_transcurridos 
from vacaciones
```

| nombre | inicio | fin | dias_transcurridos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jose | 2021/12/20 | 2021/12/24 | 3 |
| Juan | 2021/12/20 | 2021/12/20 | 0 |

la cual por lógica esta bien pero el problema es que necesito sumarle 1 dia a la columna dias_transcurridos pues aunque solo se halla tomado un dia de vacaciones y no exista cambio entre fechas se requiere un 1.

No se si alguien sabe como sumarle el 1 a toda la columna?

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, inicio, fin) + 1

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces **TIMESTAMPDIFF** y le pasas **DAY** como parametro, te retornará un valor númerico de días, así que al valor retornado solo le sumamos 1 de la siguiente manera:

```
select nombre DATE_FORMAT(inicio, "%d-%m-%Y"),
DATE_FORMAT(fin, "%d-%m-%Y"), TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, inicio, fin) + 1 AS dias_transcurridos 
from vacaciones
```

Solo le agregamos + 1 después de la función `TIMESTAMPDIFF`.

Comment: te lo agradezco mucho